# JavaFX on a 4k screen

Tags: java

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 and I am creating a javaFX application. I have used a lot of time to research google and found no way at all to make my program scale on linux. Here is how it looks like:

[image: program]

I have tried different things like adding `Dprism.allowhidpi=true` in VM options and adding `System.setProperty("prism.allowhidpi", "true");` at the start of my program which is nothing but a simple window. What could I do?

I am using openJDK 11 and openJFX 11

I have seen some people saying that you can launch the jar file with some scaling commands, the problem here is that I am coding, it's inside intellij, it's not a jar file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that javafx is looking for something which GNOME is no longer setting/not in all cases.
A quick fix is:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2` (replace 2 with the actual scaling factor you want)
and reset with

`gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor`

Others  discussing the same problem:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1713323/comments/6
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/668749/how-to-set-up-gnome-interface-for-hidpi-screen

Answer (score 1):

You might use following VM parameter specified when starting your Application. In Intellij Idea this can be done in the Run/Debug configuration:

-Dglass.gtk.uiScale=2.0

PS: It is known the DPI recognition on Linux is crap/not working on all the different Linux flavors/environments.